# CudnnLSTM runs out of space with Eager Execution

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using 3 `tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM(1, 128, direction='bidirectional')` layers with a batch size of 32 on an AWS `p2.xlarge` instance. The exact same configuration works correctly with non-eager(standard) tensorflow. Following is the error log:

```
2018-04-27 18:15:59.139739: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:1520] Failed to allocate RNN workspace of 74252288 bytes.
2018-04-27 18:15:59.139758: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:1697] Unable to create rnn workspace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_run_eager.py", line 424, in <module>
    run_experiments()
  File "tf_run_eager.py", line 417, in run_experiments
    train_losses.append(model.optimize(bX, bY).numpy())
  File "tf_run_eager.py", line 397, in optimize
    loss, grads_and_vars = self.loss(phoneme_features, utterances)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py", line 233, in grad_fn
    sources)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/imperative_grad.py", line 65, in imperative_grad
    tape._tape, vspace, target, sources, output_gradients, status)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py", line 141, in grad_fn
    op_inputs, op_outputs, orig_outputs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py", line 109, in _magic_gradient_function
    return grad_fn(mock_op, *out_grads)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/ops/cudnn_rnn_ops.py", line 1609, in _cudnn_rnn_backward
    direction=op.get_attr("direction"))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/ops/gen_cudnn_rnn_ops.py", line 320, in cudnn_rnn_backprop
    _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to call ThenRnnBackward [Op:CudnnRNNBackprop]
```

Comment: As a workaround for now I'm using `tf.contrib.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.contrib.keras.layers.LSTM())`.

Comment: Another followup - that crashes too - the crash also randomly happens with a batch size of 16.